# Making an instagram posting bot with python?

Tags: python, instagram

Ok so I know nothing about programming with python yet but I have wanted to make a bot to post to instagram for a while so thought it would be a good way to 'hit the ground running'.

I dont have a specific time frame so no rush.

I don't know any programming languages yet but have wanted to branch out since I use a GUI based web automaiton tool which I see has quite alot of overlap with programming languages such as if statements, variables, loops etc.

I have been feeling that learning a proper language will be a better investment long term.

So since I know nothing about it, but I have my goal in mind can people suggest what where I start in terms of what I should study for the task? Then I can laser focus what I need to learn and work at it piece by piece.

I want to just upload pictures as one operation and follow/unfollow as another on instagram. So please illuminate me on how Id go about that. I was told that python is the best all rounder to learn since it does everything in a tidy fashion ie less code and is intuitive. I will want to make other projects in future based on web automation so felt this would be a good one to learn from what I was told by a pro programmer.

I understand I may have been vague but not sure what to ask yet given my ignorance so please ask away if needed to hone the question/s.

Comment: You can use this script from github https://github.com/instabot-py/instabot.py . Had some friends recommending me this.

Answer (score 9):

With Instagram there is no need to do "web automation", because there is an API that you can simply work with.

It's even easier than this, there is a python library ready to use: https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram

As a sidepoint, I cannot resist to comment your sentence "I was told that python is the best all rounder to learn since it does everything in a tidy fashion ie less code and is intuitive.".

Python is indeed a good language to learn, but all languages have theirs pros and cons, so try to forget the idea that "there is a best language". If that was the case, we would all use the same one and not bother learning many of them :)

Comment: Sure I get your point, but I think the person said to me its the best one to learn first and the other ones would be clear from there. I think that was the message.

Answer (score 6):

You should note that while you can follow and unfollow users and like and unlike media. you CAN NOT post to Instagram using their API.

Comment: Ye this was the problem I found already when using the browser based viewers.

My current solution had been to use windows automation and vbox with phone emulator installed but it would be nicer to streamline it with a proper bot.

Comment: Soemone who is a programmer was saying something about how I would have to sniff out somehow what is coming 'down the line' when using instagram and replicate it. They were more detailed, I have the message saved.

Comment: Yeah we did that...and a colleague swiftly got his account banned after 4 posts. There's a reason their posting API is private and its not to make it difficult. They want tight control over what gets posted to Instagram and how.

Edit: It's a slippery slope problem. They are not only trying to prevent people creating spamming accounts. But they are also trying to limit the damage someone could do if they got your access token and started spamming accounts. Just look at facebook and spam Phishing posts like "Hey is this you...{dodgy link here}"

Comment: You can utilize Instagram's private API, see https://github.com/mr0re1/pynstagram library for example.

Comment: I wouldn't use anything like that. You are likely to get you account banned and you app blacklisted from their api. It's called private for a reason

Answer (score 1):

Do you have some initial programming experience already? If not, take a quick introduction into the world of python. There exist tons of good information sources/[tutorials](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) already.

In order to communicate with Instagram you will be interacting with the [Instagram API](https://instagram.com/developer/?hl=en). This is a set of functions that are provided by Instagram and that allow you to interact with their data. These interactions occur with http requests and they are often formatted in json.

Luckily in python there exists a library that already encapsulates most of these API interactions, which can be found [here](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram). This way you do not have to worry about the http requests part, which I believe can be quite hard for a beginner. If you feel a little comfortable with python, you should go through the read-me file of the github project; it should give you a basic idea of how to get started.

Comment: As I said I haven't done any coding in terms of writing lines in a pad :). But this program: http://zennolab.com/en/products/zennoposter/ Ive used for around 3 years. I don't know what it would classify as? a scripting tool maybe? When I was watching a python intro I saw quite a few familiar things such as syntax for doing checks of text like if exists if doesnt exist and so forth. And the things I mentioned in my OP. So I don't know if that counts as experience or not :).

Comment: I see. I've looked into the program you linked. It seems like a good introduction to get the hang of programming concepts. Still I would advice you to look at the original tutorial (which I linked), but perhaps the link Joachim gave is better fitted for people new to coding; CodeAcademy offers a good set of tutorials which starts from scratch. The advantage of CodeAcademy is that their tutorial consists of small tasks, so you don't have to come up with exercises yourself. When you feel comfortable enough in the language, move on to your Instagram problem.

Comment: Ah thanks for taking a look glad you think so :). Started on the code academy ones now. So far so good :)

Answer (score 1):

A idea is to use *Selenium*, *webdriver* and *chromedriver* to open a Chrome tab, login into the account and do some job like click in some place, do something, etc. Example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep, strftime
from random import randint
import pandas as pd

optionss = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
optionss.binary_location = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome Beta/Application/chrome.exe' # Directory where your chrome.exe is
chrome_driver_binary = './chromedriver.exe' # Change this to your own chromedriver path! 
webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_binary, options=optionss)
sleep(2)
webdriver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher')
sleep(3)

username = webdriver.find_element_by_name('username')
username.send_keys('YOUR-USERNAME')
password = webdriver.find_element_by_name('password')
password.send_keys('YOUR-PASS')

button_login = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[normalize-space()="Login"]')
button_login.click()
sleep(4)

notnow = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[normalize-space()="Not now"]')
notnow.click() #comment these last 2 lines out, if you don't get a pop up asking about notifications
sleep(2)

##############
### From here, put the tasks you want to be done,
### like click to send image, etc, etc. 
### You need to study the html code.
##############
```

Depending on the task to be performed, put some *sleep()* between one and the other to avoid having your account to be suspended for some time.

To get those *XPath*, I use Opera browser. Right click > Inspect element > *Find the html code* > Right click on this html code > Copy > Copy XPath or Full XPath

And use this into the *find_element_by_xpath*. Have many ways to do this... choose yours.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you have never programmed before the Instagram thing might not be a good first project. It is a good motivational mid-term goal though.

Check out interactive tutorials like https://www.codecademy.com/tracks/python

Comment: I agree, but I thought it is good to have something to shoot for :).

Answer (score 0):

I have used this api for posting on instagram
https://github.com/LevPasha/Instagram-API-python
Here's the code:

```
from InstagramAPI import InstagramAPI
InstagramAPI = InstagramAPI(user,pwd)
InstagramAPI.login() # login
photo_path ='path to image'
caption = "your caption"
InstagramAPI.uploadPhoto(photo_path, caption = caption)
```

Comment: hello, I get this UnboundLocalError: local variable 'InstagramAPI' referenced before assignment when trying to use your code.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit heavy, but you can use Selenium and do a bot on your browser. You can even make automatic clicks on the window if you don't want to read web codes.

Answer (score 0):

I began looking into this issue in earnest recently. All of the APIs that used to be able to do this have been shut down by Instagram and they may even ban your account if they find that you are.

I came up with a pretty simple solution using Python, Selenium and Docker.
Just install Docker and follow the instructions:

https://github.com/RunlevelConsulting/Automate-Instagram-Uploads

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that many of the answers are quite old and that they don't work in 2021, so here is the newest working method for Instagram bot.

I am using instabot python library, that allows you to upload post, stories, videos, make comments and much more. It has some issues but this code takes care about all of that for you. Enjoy!

```
from instabot import Bot
import os
import shutil


def clean_up():
    dir = "config"
    remove_me = "imgs\img.jpg.REMOVE_ME"
    # checking whether config folder exists or not
    if os.path.exists(dir):
        try:
            # removing it so we can upload new image
            shutil.rmtree(dir)
        except OSError as e:
            print("Error: %s - %s." % (e.filename, e.strerror))
    if os.path.exists(remove_me):
        src = os.path.realpath("imgs\img.jpg")
        os.rename(remove_me, src)


def upload_post():
    bot = Bot()

    bot.login(username="your_username", password="your_password")
    bot.upload_photo("imgs/img.jpg", caption="Caption for the post")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    clean_up()
    upload_post()
```

Comment: If anyone runs into some bugs or errors let me know and I will try to help.

Comment: Note that it is necessary to change the path "imgs/img.jpg" to folder where you store images that you want to upload.

Comment: I am getting error:
ERROR - Photo Upload failed with the following response: <Response [400]>
2021-08-12 16:26:37,978 - INFO - Photo 'bigshoeslover.jpg' is not uploaded.
2021-08-12 16:26:37,982 - INFO - Total requests: 31

Answer (score -5):

> So since I know nothing about it, but I have my goal in mind can
>   people suggest what where I start in terms of what I should study for
>   the task? Then I can laser focus what I need to learn and work at it
>   piece by piece.

Hard to answer. but I will try my best.

On Github there's a great [instagram bot project](https://github.com/instabot-py/instabot.py). you can try your hands on. But as you try you will realize that you can't understand the project without learning the basic concepts of python.

So, start with [Sololearn](https://www.sololearn.com/). Similar to Stack overflow, Sololearn has a huge community. (unlike stack overflow sololearn's community is friendly)